# Can not transform code with babel transform with config file

Tags: babeljs, babel-cli, babel-core

This is the config file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
    ]
}
```

This is the command:

```
npx babel src/* --out-dir build
```

The CLI output is

```
src/script.js -> build\src\script.js
```

The output script file is identical to the input script file.

---

This is the node.js file:

```js
const babel = require('@babel/core');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync(
    'build/index.js',
    babel.transformFileSync(
        'src/index.js',
        {
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
        }
    ).code
);
```

The output script file's content is what is expected.

---

I used this as input:

```
const test = 0;
export default { test };
```

This is the output from the CLI command shown above.

```
const test = 0;
export default { test };
```

This is the output from the NodeJS file shown above (which is my expected output from the CLI).

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports["default"] = void 0;
var test = 0;
var _default = {
  test: test
};
exports["default"] = _default;
```

---

**Q:** Can you you babel CLI to transform code?

Comment: Are you using a [project wide configuration in the root folder or a file-relative one](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files)?

Comment: Could you add some more details about what type of transformation you are expecting to see which is not occurring? :)

Comment: Also what are the contents of `src/script.js`?  At first I thought it was the node file that you posted, but it seems like that is how you are executing babel?

Comment: In the new update of the post I've included more details and contents (IO). Using a project-wide configuration in the root folder didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used babel-node in scenario where we want to transpile.  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html

```
npx babel-node src/* --out-dir build
```

Comment: It doesn't meet my requirements, e.g. babel-node doesn't support glob as input of file.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why [transform, which is an async function](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core#transform), is being used inside a synchroous, blocking execution. Instead use [transformSync and .code](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core#transformsync)

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    'build/script.js',
    babel.transformSync(
        fs.readFileSync('src/script.js').toString('utf8'),
        {
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
        }
    ).code
);
```

Or even more, you can use [transformFileSync](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core#transformfilesync):

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    'build/script.js',
    babel.transformFileSync(
        'src/script.js',
        {
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
        }
    ).code
);
```

Comment: The babel transform with node worked, but that's not it. I want to have babel run a command, not a javascript file.